# Loop Through Every Model In Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-models

In django, is there a way to loop through each model that is currently in your database?

I would like to be able to have a function that gets the total number of rows in all of my models, per model, without having to the function every time I added a new model.

the output being something like

**model1 rows: 23**

**model2 rows:234**

and then if I were to add a new model it would automatically output

**model1 rows: 23**

**model2 rows:234**

**model3 rows:0**

the ideal format would be something like.

```
def getDbStatus()
    for m in Models:
        print(m.objects.count)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `get_models()` and `count()`

```
import django.apps
for model in django.apps.apps.get_models():
    name = model.__name__
    count = model.objects.all().count()
    print("{} rows: {}".format(name, count))
```